# SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server - Sending emails through a private host

Tags: python, django, django-email

I registered a domain and a private email using `namecheap.com`. I am trying to send an email from this private email. However, I get the error in the title.

In my `settings.py`, I have these settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'contact@mysite.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

And I am trying to send my mail through a view:

```
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'contact@mysite.com',
    ['myname@gmail.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

I get this error :

```
SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Comment: Try adding `SMTP_ENABLED = True`

Answer (score 12):

This is happening because you have conflicting settings:

```
EMAIL_PORT = 587        # Port 587 is reserved for TLS
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False   # But you have disabled TLS
```

You either need to set `EMAIL_USE_TLS` to `True` or use the default port for unencrypted connections (`25`).

Answer (score 4):

I was searching answer for this since 4 hours. I still dont know why this configuration works for me, but yes, IT WORKS for me.

I simply removed,

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

from my settings.py, and add below configuration in settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username@domain.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following config since "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by" your EMAIL_HOST:

```
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using a server that is not Gmail by default and turns out to be a port issue, I found that I was using the wrong port, I changed it to  465 for SMTP with TLS, Thanks to this [link..](https://kunder.support/knowledgebase/400/SSL-vs-TLS-vs-STARTTLS.html#:%7E:text=POP%20uses%20port%20110%20%2C%20but,encrypted%20SMTP%20uses%20port%20465%20.)

So here are the settings I used:

```
EMAIL_PORT = 465       
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```